# No compiler diagnostic when identifier in a simple-capture appears as the declarator-id of a parameter

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer

The section on lambda captures [([expr.prim.lambda.capture]/5](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#capture-5)) states that

> If an identifier in a simple-capture appears as the declarator-id of a parameter of the lambda-declarator's parameter-declaration-clause, the program is ill-formed.

Consider the follow example:

```
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    auto foo = 1234;
    auto bar = [foo](int foo) { std::cout << foo << '\n'; };
    bar(4321);     
}
```

The latest GCC version (8.2.0 - released on July 26, 2018) has no diagnostic for this. Neither does latest Clang version (7.0.0 - released on Sep 19, 2018).

Should there be a diagnostic (error/warning) from these compilers (as mentioned
in the reference) along the lines of:

```
// parameter and simple-capture have the same name
```

Godbolt Demo [here](https://godbolt.org/z/2V-882)

Comment: actually I dont really see the problem with the example. Looks like shadowing that in other places is not an error, though from the paragraph you quote i'd also expect this to be an error

Comment: @user463035818 - A misconception. Shadowing is already an error under certain circumstances. For instance, you can't shadow a function parameter in the functions immediate block.

Comment: @StoryTeller well really a misconception then. Thanks for pointing it out. I always thought shadowing is fine everywhere....

Comment: @user463035818 - That's probably because you, like any other sane person, won't feel the urge to shadow something they only just defined as a function parameter :) It's only really those pathological cases that the standard flags as ill-formed.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That wording was added to C++17 to resolve [CWG Defect 2211](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2211). It didn't exist in C++14, and it would seem that Clang and GCC haven't caught up to this change up to the versions you are checking.

It's worth noting that the GCC trunk does indeed diagnose that program as ill-formed under C++17.

Comment: Is there any way to check if a compiler version takes into account such updates to the standard? Comparing the dates doesn't seem to help. Proposed resolution of this issue on February, 2017. GCC 8.2 released on July 26, 2018.

Comment: @P.W - In general? No. This is all subject to a compiler's development process, release notes and documentation.

Comment: It's fixed in clang trunk now :)